# How to copy debug *pdb file using post build event command line in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a class library project seperate from the website. When I build the seperate class library and I move ddl the website bin directory however it doesn't move *pdb file.

Post-Build event command Line option in the class library

I use

```
copy /y "$(TargetPath)" "E:\inetpub\Site\bin\"
```

to copy dll however it doesn't move the debug *pdb file and I want to move both files. How can I do that? Is it possible with macro builder. If yes, can some one tell me the steps?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try the following

```
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" "E:\inetpub\Site\bin\"
```

The macros expand as follows

- `$(TargetDir)` path to tho output directory for binaries
- `$(TargetName)` Name of the primary output minus the extension