# How to force visual studio to copy some files during build time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm building an application which is written with Qt in Visual Studio 2008.  Everything is OK and I can run the output, but the executable file depends on some other files to be loaded at run-time.  These files need to be copied along with the .EXE file every time they are changed, as I need to run the released output outside the IDE.

Is it possible to copy some files/folder in the output directory right besides the .EXE file during project build-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it's done:

1. Go to your solution explorer and open project properties
2. Select "Build events" tab
3. Enter post build command. You can also use Macros (not sure for VS2008. VS2010 already supports them)

Here is good resource for build events from where you can continue further:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: How can you get files to be copied prior to running/debugging even if building does not occur?

Comment: Use Pre-build event command line. Here is file copy sample command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075802/how-to-copy-debug-pdb-file-using-post-build-event-command-line-in-visual-studio

Comment: Will pre-build work even if a build doesn't occur?  I am modifying XML files used for configuration that don't affect a build but will affect the project's execution when I run the debugger.

Comment: This page says pre-build events don't run if the project is up-to-date:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: In this case go to solution explorer, make right click on your project and click Clean. This will cleanup builds so before next app run Pre-Build and new build will always occur.

Comment: That would be inefficient because my project is huge.  I don't want to rebuild everything simply because I modified a single XML config file.

Answer (score 1):

If using Visual Studio right mouse click the file you want copied to the output folder, select Properties. In the Advanced section, the second option is: Copy to Output Directory. By default this is "Do not copy". Select the other options as desired such as "Copy always" or 'Copy if newer". These properties will be saved to your .csproj file.